# The run method of Java thread does not take the updated status

Tags: java, multithreading

The code below is my run method. This **stat** status does not take the newly updated status from my stop method.

```
@Override
public void run() {

    synchronized (this) {

        while (!stat) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TrafficLightSimulator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }            }
    }
}
```

In the above code, the program does not enter while loop. It is because the stat boolean new changed value from the stop method is not taken in run method.

This is my new stop

```
public void stop() {
        synchronized(this) {
            this.stopStat = false;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

I even defined the stat as the volatile boolean variable. However, this also does not seem to work.

Comment: Your entire loop is running inside the monitor.

Comment: However, is there any reason why the run method does not take the true status even after the method is called?

Comment: Have you call `notify`?

Comment: I did call `notify`.

Comment: no `notify` in posted code - maybe a [mcve] would be of help instead of having ppl guessing

Answer (score 2):

While you have the "waiting" part correct, your "setting" part is missing some important parts.

The first part that is missing is the lock:

```
public void stop() {
    synchronized(this) {
        this.stat = true;
    }
}
```

This lock makes sure that only 1 thread can change/access it at the same time, as is required by the [Java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4). Without this lock (and without `volatile)`, Java makes no guarantee that changes to this variable are seen by other threads.

The next part that missing is the notifying part, it is important to "wake" up all waiting threads when the condition is changed:

```
public void stop() {
    synchronized(this) {
        this.stat = true;
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

The last part of your error happens due the fact you are setting the variable to true, while for the code to be inside the while loop, the variable is already true. You probably want to set it to `false` instead

```
public void stop() {
    synchronized(this) {
        this.stat = false;
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the stat to false. However, the code still does not work.

Comment: @SrijanKarki If I read your question more clear, it sems like your initial state if false, and you want to set it to true, and then run the code after the while loop. If that is the case, notice that the while loop only loops when the variable if "truety", so add an exclamation mark in front of the stat variable

Comment: I did that Thanks. Still nothing.

Comment: Re, "we don't want the reader seeing a half update." That is not an issue with a `boolean` variable. The Java language specification guarantees that when a thread looks at any `int`, `float`, or `boolean` variable or, at any object reference, the thread will either see the initital value, or it will see a value that the program stored in the variable. It is impossible for any thread to see a "half update" of any of those types.

Comment: The reason to use `synchronized` is because of Java's _[memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)_.  Any thread that locks a lock is guaranteed to see all of the updates that were made by some other thread before the other thread previously unlocked the same lock.  Without the locking, the JLS makes no guarantee about if or when the values stored in non-volatile variables by thread A will become visible to thread B.

Answer (score 1):

Memory visibility isn't an issue here because both the code reading the flag and the code setting the flag are synchronized, holding the same lock. If your code won't enter the while loop it must be that some other thread has the lock.

This is another reason (in addition to the reasons below) to use interrupt instead of wait/notify for this. Interruption doesn't depend on acquiring a lock to work.

Use interrupt for this instead. There's no good reason for your own flag here when one is provided for you, using wait/notify for this is unnecessary and can cause problems since you may need to wait/notify for other reasons.

The Java api docs advise against locking on threads, by the way. That's what join does. Implicit locking doesn't have a way to have different conditions get separate notifications for a lock (the way ReentrantLock does).

For a thread that does things with intermittent sleeps in between, the run method can look like:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            doStuff();
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // no need to log this as an error, it's not an error
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Real world code uses threadpools where you submit Runnable or Callable tasks, the java.util.concurrent classes expect your code to handle interruption.

Comment: I did set the stat to false. However, I can only use interrupt when the user clicks the STOP button as that should be the trigger. Yet when the stop button is clicked the stop method is called but the changed status cannot be accessed in the run method.